# SQLite database directory in intellij idea

Tags: android, database, sqlite, intellij-idea

I am trying some simple **android** codes in **intellij IDEA.**
I have an .db SQLite DataBase of words.
But I Dont know witch Directory of project I have to Paste the DB file
 I Opened this DB like this :

```
 try {
            db=openOrCreateDatabase("data.db", 1,null);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERR:"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

and used like this :
try
                {

```
                Cursor c;
                c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM words WHERE en='"+ed.getText()+"'",null);
                v.append(c.getString(1));

            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERR:"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you leave it to a Framework to do... but in your case it's pretty simple

You /assets/

Create it like so...

```
As for DB_NAME = "yourfilename.db"
As for DB_NAME = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
   }
```

Comment: i had copied my data.db in assets ! but problem remains :(

Comment: Can you please put some exception trace, in here?